# python: integer solution in a system with more variables than equations

Tags: python, integer, linear-algebra, equation

I would like to find a integer solution to a system of equations. For my problem, the system has a number of equations but more variables than that. This means that there are likely many integer solutions, but finding just one would be sufficient.

for example:

```
5a+0b+0c+7d+1e+2f+0g=10
2a+3b+0c+3d+4e+0f+9g=10
0a+2b+6c+0d+6e+2f+7g=10
0a+2b+6c+0d+3e+0f+1g=10
3a+0b+4c+1d+0e+3f+7g=10
```

the algorithm finds one (of possibly many) integer solution:

```
a=2, b=2, c=1, d=0, e=0, f=0, g=0
```

All questions and algorithms that I have found online were either requiring the same amount of equations and variables, or didn't return only integer values. Is there a library or algorithm that does this?

thanks in advance,
Aron

Comment: The problem is an example of what is known as Diophantine equation.
There seems to be a general method of solving it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#System_of_linear_Diophantine_equations